# Difference between Logic Chip and Memory Chip front-end manufacturing process?

Tags: semiconductors, fabrication, semiconductor-process-technology

I understand that memory chips like DRAM Chips require a little different set of Front-end setup than logics chips. However, I am not finding anywhere how the actual manufacturing steps differ, especially the front-end manufacturing process. I'm trying to understand if a Fab is set to manufacture processors can it be reconfigured to make memory chips without lets say "equipment layout change"?

Answer (score 2):

Memory processes differ from logic in a couple of ways:

- specialized structures, like deep-well caps for DRAM or floating gates for Flash
- lower leakage / higher threshold voltage (trade speed for standby power)
- fewer metal layers to keep costs down

That said, it’s possible to make logic on DRAM process. Conversely, adapting a logic line for DRAM may require some retrofit and recalibration.